# Unable to start Gradle daemon. And Project won't load due to non ASCII characters

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, jvm, 32-bit

I have installed android studio latest version 3.1.2 on my window 7(32), but I installed it before the installation of Java JDK, and when it installed I don't import my old projects, then I have a problem in the build.gradle, also in daemon if I opened old project, but if I open new project there is a problem in non-ASCII characters.
[image]

[image]

I want to know what is the problem:
Is it bcz I installed it before JDK?
or bcz don't import old projects?
or bcz initialization of VM?

Comment: First problem is too little memory. Second problem is clearly saying that your project directory has non-ASCII characters. So just rename the folder

Comment: I edited it and worked for me, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete this in `gradle.properties`

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
```

and add

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I edited it and worked for me , but I think I must edit that in every old project , right?

Comment: Maybe, If you get error in that project then need to change it.